# Resample PCM network stream to 8000Hz 8-bit mono via libsndfile sf_open_virtual function

Tags: c++, node.js, pcm, resampling, libsndfile

My goal is to take a PCM stream in Node.js that is, even for example, 44100Hz 16 bit stereo, and then resample it to 8000 Hz 8 bit mono to then be encoded into Opus and then streamed.

My thought was to try making bindings for libsndfile in C++ and using sf_open_virtual function for resampling on the stream. However:

1. How can I reply to its callback function requesting a certain amount
   of data (found here:
   http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#open_virtual) if my
   program is still receiving data from the network? Do I just let it
   hang in a loop until the loop detects that the buffer is a certain
   percent full?
2. Since the PCM data is going to be headerless, how can
   I specify the format type for libsndfile to expect?

Or am I over-complicating things totally?

Comment: I don't know anything about node.js, but I can tell you that `sf_open_virtual()` will not work, because it needs to know the length of the whole file *when opening*. If you manage to get a file descriptor or a named pipe where your PCM data is written to, it should work fine, though. Then you can simply open the file descriptor/pipe with the major type "RAW" and the subtype "PCM_16" and you will be able to read data even if new data is still coming in.

Comment: everything without a header will fail...     SF_INFO sfinfo;
    sfinfo.channels = 1;
    sfinfo.samplerate = 44100;
    sfinfo.format = SF_FORMAT_PCM_32 | SF_FORMAT_RAW;

Pass &sfinfo in open and libsndfile will read headerless raw data